# nginx Content-Security-Policy Header still blocking bootstrapcdn

Tags: nginx, content-security-policy, nginx-location

I have the following in my nginx.conf

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy 
    "default-src 'self'; 
    img-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: *.printfriendly.com *.w.org *.gravatar.com *.vimeocdn.com; 
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.w.org *.gravatar.com *.googleapis.com *.jsdelivr.net *.printfriendly.com *.kxcdn.com *.vimeocdn.com *.hs-analytics.net *.securitymetrics.com *.google-analytics.com; 
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.googleapis.com *.bootstrapcdn.com *.gstatic.com *.vimeocdn.com; 
    font-src 'self' data: *.googleapis.com *.bootstrapcdn.com *.gstatic.com *.googleapis.com; 
    frame-src 'self' *.vimeocdn.com *.vimeo.com; 
    object-src 'self'";
```

(i had to multi-line it to make it legible...)

However, in my site I am still getting this error:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css (“style-src”).
```

Any ideas why this may be happenning, when it is whitelisted above?

Comment: Where have you used this in your `nginx` config? Do remember that adding another `add_header` anywhere will discard this one  if not in the same block

Comment: this is done in the primary nginx.conf file.  So it's global

Comment: Please share the output from `nginx -T`

Comment: Can you also try adding `always` at the end of the of your `add_header` directive, just before the `;` and see if that helps? @Kevin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @tarun-lalwani mentioned, **any** `add_header` directive in another blocks can matter. More precisely, if `add_header` (for any header) is used in a descendant block, this Content-Security-Policy will be discarded in such descendant block.

An excerpt from the [documentation](http://nginx.org/r/add_header):

> These directives are inherited from the previous level if and only if
> there are no `add_header` directives defined on the current level.

To avoid code copy (DRY) the variables or `include` directive can be used (or generating nginx config in extensive case).

Just in case, in a real config a multi-line header value should not be used. Check your server response via `curl -I https://example.com/path`. For better readability in the config the variables can be used.

Example:

```
set $CSP_image  "img-src      'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: *.printfriendly.com *.w.org *.gravatar.com *.vimeocdn.com; ";
set $CSP_script "script-src   'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.w.org *.gravatar.com *.googleapis.com *.jsdelivr.net *.printfriendly.com *.kxcdn.com *.vimeocdn.com *.hs-analytics.net *.securitymetrics.com *.google-analytics.com; ";
set $CSP_style  "style-src    'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.googleapis.com *.bootstrapcdn.com *.gstatic.com *.vimeocdn.com; ";
set $CSP_font   "font-src     'self' data: *.googleapis.com *.bootstrapcdn.com *.gstatic.com *.googleapis.com; ";
set $CSP_frame  "frame-src    'self' *.vimeocdn.com *.vimeo.com; ";
set $CSP_object "object-src   'self' ; ";
set $CSP        "default-src  'self' ; ${CSP_image} ${CSP_script} ${CSP_style} ${CSP_font} ${CSP_frame} ${CSP_object}";

add_header Content-Security-Policy $CSP;
```

Comment: appreciate the readability :)  However, there are no other headers set.

Comment: @kevin, can you see the CSP header in output from `curl`? If yes — the issue is not in nginx configuration. If no — you need to debug your config step by step. Don't forget to reload the config by `nginx -s reload`. To get further help you have to publish your config (for example, on pastebin.com).

Comment: I can see them in curl output.  And like the good tool that I am, I completely overlooked the fact that the resource I have in the question is http:// and not https://   Which, I would bet is what the issue is

Comment: I have just implemented this example and it's working brilliantly. Thankyou